# Slide out side bar with sub categories

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am using SWRevealViewController.[image]

These are some rows in table view. Each row opens a new view.
Now I want to show some sub categories/rows on click of Services and vice versa.
The sub categories will be like Designing, Development, Applications etc.
and each of this sub category opens different view.
I am using only 1 section. Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

You can use UIPopoverContoller containing UITableView for subCategories
Here is the link for UIPopover https://github.com/alvises/FPPopover
As UIPopover is for ipad so in iphone u will have import thirdparty library mention above.

Comment: Sorry but I don't want to use this approach and style.

Answer (score 0):

you can use these MMDrawerController containing UITableview for Slide out side bar with sub categories,it has very good animation styles for side bar..

https://github.com/mutualmobile/MMDrawerController

i hope it helps..

Comment: Not exactly what I'm looking for. Want it to be just like flipkart etc.

Answer (score 0):

Use following steps to implement expandable cells

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";   
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier] autorelease];
}
cell.textLabel.text=[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"name"];
[cell setIndentationLevel:[[[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row] valueForKey:@"level"] intValue]];    
return cell;
```

}

This is the method TableView DidSelectRow Method for expanding and  collapsing rows

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
[tableView deselectRowAtIndexPath:indexPath animated:YES];
NSDictionary *d=[self.arForTable objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
if([d valueForKey:@"Objects"]) {
    NSArray *ar=[d valueForKey:@"Objects"];
    BOOL isAlreadyInserted=NO;
    for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ){
        NSInteger index=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        isAlreadyInserted=(index>0 && index!=NSIntegerMax);
        if(isAlreadyInserted) break; 
    }
    if(isAlreadyInserted) {
        [self miniMizeThisRows:ar];
    } else {        
        NSUInteger count=indexPath.row+1;
        NSMutableArray *arCells=[NSMutableArray array];
        for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
            [arCells addObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:count inSection:0]];
            [self.arForTable insertObject:dInner atIndex:count++];
        }
        [tableView insertRowsAtIndexPaths:arCells withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationLeft];
    }
}
}
```

Method to expand and minimize the cells

```
(void)miniMizeThisRows:(NSArray*)ar{
for(NSDictionary *dInner in ar ) {
    NSUInteger indexToRemove=[self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];        
    NSArray *arInner=[dInner valueForKey:@"Objects"];
    if(arInner && [arInner count]>0){
        [self miniMizeThisRows:arInner];
    }
    if([self.arForTable indexOfObjectIdenticalTo:dInner]!=NSNotFound) {
        [self.arForTable removeObjectIdenticalTo:dInner];
        [self.tableView deleteRowsAtIndexPaths:
          [NSArray arrayWithObject:[NSIndexPath indexPathForRow:indexToRemove inSection:0]]
                  withRowAnimation:UITableViewRowAnimationRight];
    }
}
}
```

Comment: Its showing 2 errors. No visible interface for insertObject, removeObjectIdenticalTo. How to fix these

Comment: Make all arrays global and add @property (nonatomic, strong)  before the variable